# My correlation model does not work when I combine numerics with more than one categorical variables in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Im trying to combine the selection of multiple categorical and numeric variable to find correlations between them in a `shiny` app but while it works for one categorical variable it does not when I select more than one.

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

var1 <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
var2 <- c(2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 6.5)

# Create categorical variables
var3 <- c("red", "green", "blue", "red", "green")
var4 <- c("small", "medium", "large", "small", "medium")
var5 <- c("red1", "green1", "blue1", "red1", "green1")
var6 <- c("small1", "medium2", "large2", "small2", "medium2")
# Combine variables into a dataframe
mmtcars <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4,var5,var6)

# app page
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Task Managers' Workload Analysis",
    titleWidth = 400
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    selectInput(
      "vars", 
      "Select variables", 
      choices = colnames(mmtcars), 
      selected = colnames(mmtcars)[1:2], 
      multiple = TRUE
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    plotOutput("mlr_output")
  )
)

# server side actions
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Convert categorical variable to a factor
  mmtcars$var3 <- factor(mmtcars$var3)
  mmtcars$var4 <- factor(mmtcars$var4)
  mmtcars$var5 <- factor(mmtcars$var5)
  mmtcars$var6 <- factor(mmtcars$var6)
  
  # Subset the data into numeric and categorical variables
  numeric_vars <- mmtcars[, sapply(mmtcars, is.numeric)]
  categorical_vars <- mmtcars[, sapply(mmtcars, is.factor)]
  
  mm <- reactive({
    # Compute the correlation matrix between selected numeric and categorical variables
    selected_numeric_vars <- numeric_vars[,  names(numeric_vars) %in% input$vars]
    selected_categorical_vars <- categorical_vars[, names(categorical_vars) %in% input$vars]
    
    if (length(selected_categorical_vars)>0) {
      var_c <- as.numeric(selected_categorical_vars)-1
      df <- data.frame(selected_numeric_vars, varc  = var_c)
      names(df)[length(names(df))] <- names(categorical_vars)[names(categorical_vars) %in% input$vars]
    }else df <- data.frame(selected_numeric_vars)
    
    #correlations <- cor(selected_numeric_vars, as.numeric(selected_categorical_vars) - 1, method = "pearson")
    correlations <- cor(df)
    correlations
  })
  
  
  # print summary of correlation matrix for selected variables
  output$mlr_output <- renderPrint({mm()})
  
} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't get any results from your code without adding an `actionbutton` to perform the calculations, but I'm guessing this is part of a larger script and it works fine for you with one categorical variable.

Regarding your problem: inside the `if` statement you are assuming that `selected_categorical_vars` is a *vector*, which is only true when you select one categorical variable. When you select more than one, `selected_categorical_vars` becomes a *data.frame*, and `as.numeric(selected_categorical_vars)` crashes. You can modify the code doing something like this:

```
if (length(selected_categorical_vars)>0) {
  var_c <- apply(as.data.frame(selected_categorical_vars), MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x){as.numeric(factor(x))-1})
  df <- data.frame(selected_numeric_vars, varc  = var_c)
  names(df) <- c(intersect(names(numeric_vars),input$vars), intersect(names(categorical_vars),input$vars))
} else {df <- data.frame(selected_numeric_vars)}
```

This way it doesn't matter if `selected_categorical_vars` is a data.frame or a vector.